# Creation AVD device from Java code. Library or other solution

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, avd-manager

I try to make auto-tests with some new AVDs on Java. In my case i must create AVD for every APK run, and delete AVD after it. And i can not find a solution or library for it.

Only cli call "avdmanager create....". But this is discomfort decision because i must write in stdin answers on questions. If i want create custom AVD - its impossible (many fields to write to stdin).

In past "android create" was good decision, but now it deprecated and this command run avdmanager.

I found information about com.android.sdklib with class AVDManager, but i can not find documentation or some examples. Is it real - make new AVD devices from code?

Answer (score 0):

There's CLI commands to do it.  Just write a class with functions like createAVD that call the CLI command and waits for it to finish.  There's no reason a Java app can't call other apps.

Comment: Sorry, i did not described this variant. It impossible now, to create custom AVD. Only default with one "no" answer. Updated my first post.